# Invalid parameter error of facebook business sdk for php

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Business SDK for PHP to submit ads.

I was able to successfully create Campaigns and AdSets, but I'm having trouble creating Ads.

Specifically, I'm struggling with creating the Creative for the Ads.

I keep getting an Invalid Parameter error, so I think there's either something wrong or missing in the parameters I'm passing.

The advertisements I want to create are for Facebook's feed, marketplace, and search.

I don't need videos for now, I just want to test with images.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Facebook;

use App\Services\FacebookBusiness\Client as FacebookBusinessClient;

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdImage;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdImageFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Ad;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreative;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeLinkData;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeObjectStorySpec;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeLinkDataFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdPreviewAdFormatValues;
use FacebookAds\Api;

use FacebookAds\Exception\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class FacebookAdService extends FacebookAdsCommonService
{
    protected FacebookBusinessClient $facebookBusinessClient;

    public function __construct(FacebookBusinessClient $facebookBusinessClient)
    {
        $this->facebookBusinessClient = $facebookBusinessClient;
    }

    public function createAd(int $adSetId)
    {
        try {
            $facebookBusinessInstance = $this->facebookBusinessClient->getInstance();

            $account = new AdAccount($this->facebookBusinessClient->getAdAccountId());

            $account->setApi($facebookBusinessInstance);

            // create image hashes with the same images as test
            $images = [
                public_path('/assets/images/instagram.png'),
                public_path('/assets/images/instagram.png'),
            ];
            $imageHashes = [];

            foreach ($images as $imagePath) {
                $image = new AdImage(null, $account->id);
                $image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = $imagePath;
                $image->create();
                $imageHashes[] = $image->{AdImageFields::HASH};
            }

            // Set each card of carousel
            $linkData = new AdCreativeLinkData();
            $linkData->setData([
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => '{ myurl }',
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => $imageHashes[0],
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => ['type' => 'LEARN_MORE'],
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CHILD_ATTACHMENTS => array_map(function ($hash) {
                    return [
                        'link' => '{ myurl }',
                        'image_hash' => $hash,
                        'call_to_action' => ['type' => 'LEARN_MORE'],
                    ];
                }, $imageHashes),
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MULTI_SHARE_END_CARD => true,
                AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MULTI_SHARE_OPTIMIZED => true,
            ]);

            // set story spec
            $objectStorySpec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
            $objectStorySpec->setData([
                AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => 'my page id',
                AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $linkData->getData(),
            ]);

            // set creative
            $creative = new AdCreative(null, $account->id);
            $creative->setData([
                AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'TestCarouselCreative_' . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s'),
                AdCreativeFields::TITLE => 'Test Carousel Creative Title',
                AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $objectStorySpec->getData(),
            ]);

            Log::info('--- ▼ error ▼ ---');
            $creative->create();
            Log::info('--- ▲ error ▲ ---');

            $ad = new Ad(null, $account->id);

            $ad->setData([
                AdFields::NAME => date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . '_TestAd',
                AdFields::ADSET_ID => $adSetId,
                AdFields::CREATIVE => ['creative_id' => $creative->id],
            ]);

            $ad->create([
                Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => 'PAUSED',
            ]);

            Log::info('adId: ' . $ad->id);
    
            return $ad->id;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error('FacebookAdService error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

I keep changing the parameters to be passed and making requests, but I keep getting an Invalid error.

I can't guess from the error message what the correct parameters are.

Comment: Can you share what's error using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77575646/edit).